# How to use the live jQuery api?

Tags: jquery

I found this jquery plugin which does exactly what I need, but I want to use it on table rows which are in an update panel, so I was hoping to use the live() jquery api to somehow keep the jquery intact across the update panel requests.  Is this possible?

```
jQuery.fn.linker = function(selector) { 
    $(this).each(function() { 
        var href = $(selector, this).attr('href'); 
        if (href) { 
            var link = $('<a href="' + $(selector, this).attr('href') + '"></a>').css({ 
                'text-decoration': 'none', 
                'display': 'block', 
                'padding': '0px', 
                'color': $(this).css('color') 
            }) 
            $(this).children() 
                   .css('padding', '0') 
                   .wrapInner(link); 
        } 
    }); 
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Live Query plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs) to listen for `<tr>` element creation and then apply this functionality.

```
$("tr").livequery(function() {
  $(this).linker();
});
```

If I understand that plugin and your desired result correctly.